# How to use ref inside functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i recently convert my code to functional component so i can try hooks. i get a problem when i want to use **ScrollTo** method from ScrollView. i was using this.refs.scrollTo back then, but i cant do it now.

i've tried using useRef from hooks but it also failed. here is how i implement it

```
const boardScreen = useRef(null);
...
const nextButtonHandler = async () => {
  if (scrollPosition < (content.length - 1) * width) {
      await setScrollPosition(scrollPosition + width);
      boardScreen.current.scrollTo({ x: scrollPosition, animated: true 
    });
  }
};

<ScrollView
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled
  onMomentumScrollEnd={onScrollEnd}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  ref={boardScreen}
  onScroll={Animated.event([
    {
      nativeEvent: { 
        contentOffset: { 
          x: scrollX 
        } 
      } 
    }
  ])}
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
>
 {renderContent()}
</ScrollView>
```

any suggestion? or should i just go back using class for this problem?

Comment: Please include your entire component. You have to use `ref={boardScreen}` on an element as well.

Comment: i've edited @Tholle